# Spring Security htt basic auth doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have following simple Spring Security auth:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class UserSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

And REST controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/news")
public class SimpleController {

    @Autowired
    private ScheduleService scheduleService;

    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(value = "/update")
    public ResponseEntity<String> update() {
        log.info("Update started");
        scheduleService.update();
        log.info("Update finished");
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Done.");
    }
```

application.properites for Security:

```
...
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=123
```

**What do I expect:** unauthorized error if client doesnt provide (or invalid) credentials

**I got:** application is running without any authentication and anyone can use controller without credentials.

I tested it with Postman.

What is the problem?

**UPDATE**: base auth works on my local machine, but doesn't work on remote server.

Comment: There is no security configuration, everything is unprotected so why should you be promoted for a username/password?

Comment: What do u mean? I saw this base configuration for simple http requests.

Comment: As stated there is no security. There is no `http.authorize().anyRequest().authenticated()` or something like that. Also unless you are using Spring Boot (not apparent from the tags) you need to do more to bootstrap Spring Security.

Comment: It's Spring Boot application. `super.configure()` performs `http.authorize().anyRequest().authenticated()`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you explicitly configure basic security:

```java
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests(t -> t.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .csrf(t -> t.disable())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        }
```